# Make a var inside function with parameters javascript

Tags: javascript, function, variables, parameters

I want to be able to make custom vars in a function depending on the parameter

```
function assignTime (day) {
  var sunStart = Number($('#sunStart').val());
  var sunEnd = Number($('#sunEnd').val());
  if (sunEnd < sunStart){
    sunEnd += 12;
  schedule.sunStart = sunStart;
  schedule.sunEnd = sunEnd;
  }
}
```

I want all of the "sun" to be whatever I passthrough as the "day" parameter, how would I go about this?

Comment: No, you can't do that. But you can make the strings in the `'#sunStart'` selectors and in the `schedule.sunStart` property accesses dynamic.

Comment: Yes and no. No, you can't do what you say, but yes, you can as long as you declare them as properties on some object. E.g. `start[day] = ... ` and `end[day] = ...`, with the `start` and `end` objects declared at, or higher than, the level of the function `assignTime` (with a corresponding change to your schedule assignments)